# something happens when I add .value in different locations

Tags: javascript, dom

so I tried to add .value in two differnet locations
and I just would like to know why

HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Guess My Number!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Guess My Number!</h1>
      <p class="between">(Between 1 and 20)</p>
      <button class="btn again">Again!</button>
      <div class="number">?</div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <input type="number" class="guess" name="number" />
        <button class="btn check">Check!</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript code 1 :

```
var input = document.querySelector(".guess").value
const check = document.querySelector(".check")
const message = document.querySelector(".message")
var score = document.querySelector('.score')
var highScore = document.querySelector('.highscore')

check.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(input)
})
```

result : will not log the input's value

javascript code 2 :

```
var input = document.querySelector(".guess")
const check = document.querySelector(".check")
const message = document.querySelector(".message")
var score = document.querySelector('.score')
var highScore = document.querySelector('.highscore')

check.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(input.value)
})
```

result: will log the input's value

Comment: Your first example *does* log the input's value, but it is empty because you stored the value once before any input was entered. The second example stores the *input element* and then retrieves it's value in your click handler.

Comment: @pilchard yes thanks alot I get it now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case it gets the value when the page loads, in the second when you click the button it gets the value again, updated from the input